# Elixir MongoDB export data to file

Tags: mongodb, elixir

i am newbie to elixir. i am learning elixir bcz it is concurrent and fast. i have huge number of data in MongoDB. i want to export some data to CSV or comma separated file.

I am useing following MongoDB driver in elixir. https://github.com/ankhers/mongodb

i have create new mix app suing `mix new mongo_elixir` app. and inside that i have added following code.

```
def export() do
    import Supervisor.Spec

    children = [
      worker(Mongo, [[name: :mongo, database: "test_table", pool: DBConnection.Poolboy]])
    ]

    opts = [strategy: :one_for_one, name: MongodbExport.Supervisor]
    Supervisor.start_link(children, opts)

    file = File.stream!("a.txt")
    cursor = Mongo.find(:mongo, "ssd", %{}, limit: 100000, pool: DBConnection.Poolboy)
    cursor
    |> Enum.map(fn record -> Map.get(record, "status") end)
    |> Enum.into(file)


  end
```

if i run above code using this command `time mix run -e 'MongodbExport.export()' its output is

```
Compiling 1 file (.ex)

real    0m8.134s
user    0m7.160s
sys 0m2.718s
```

it taking 8 sec to get 100_000 and write into text file. that is just simple .txt file.

but if i use following csv module
https://github.com/beatrichartz/csv

and write above data into the file its taking around 24sec. means 3x time then .txt file. i don't know why.

Can i create CSV file of 100_000 records with in 5sec to 8sec using elixir with mongoDb?. and yes if i just want to create .txt file with comma separated rows, with selected columns from data which i have got from mongo query. i am putting down 2 records.

```
  [%{
"_id" => #BSON.ObjectId<59df8a37a971f13e2caea76e>,
"business" => #BSON.ObjectId<58e362130368e8f94f503f48>,
"causeAggregator" => "SERVICE_DOWN",
"causeId" => "3425156827238253899",
"corporate" => nil,
"createdAt" => 1507822135626.0,
"loopedTimes" => 0,
"optin" => false,
"phoneNumber" => "9876543210",
"scheduledAt" => nil,
"senderId" => nil,
"sentAt" => 1507822139920.0,
"sentSms" => #BSON.ObjectId<59df8a37a971f13e2caea4ac>,
"smsCreditsUsed" => 0,
"smsRef" => #BSON.ObjectId<59df8a37a971f13e2caea4c5>,
"status" => "failed",
"statusAggregator" => "fail",
"transactionId" => nil,
"updatedAt" => 1507836544930.0
},
  %{
    "_id" => #BSON.ObjectId<59df8a37a971f13e2caea76f>,
    "business" => #BSON.ObjectId<58e362130368e8f94f503f48>,
    "causeAggregator" => "SUCCESS",
    "causeId" => "3425156827238253899",
    "corporate" => nil,
    "createdAt" => 1507822135626.0,
    "dndStatusExtracted" => true,
    "loopedTimes" => 0,
    "optin" => false,
    "phoneNumber" => "9876543210",
    "scheduledAt" => nil,
    "senderId" => nil,
    "sentAt" => 1507822139920.0,
    "sentSms" => #BSON.ObjectId<59df8a37a971f13e2caea4ac>,
    "smsCreditsUsed" => 3,
    "smsRef" => #BSON.ObjectId<59df8a37a971f13e2caea4c6>,
    "status" => "completed",
    "statusAggregator" => "success",
    "transactionId" => nil,
    "updatedAt" => 1510627097023.0
  }]
```

`

Comment: Can you try this package and see if it's faster: https://github.com/plataformatec/nimble_csv?

Comment: okay wait i will try and let u know here

Comment: i am bit confuse with this module, i dont know how to write into file??. sorry i am noob.

Comment: @Dogbert it was giving me error. any other solutions?

Comment: The field names will be all be fixed or variable based on the record?

Comment: @TarunLalwani record base,

Comment: @TarunLalwani did u found any solution for this?

Comment: sorry for wrong communication in previous comment. i have deleted that. your solution is not faster i was just trying 2  3 options, so got confused in my code and your suggestions result is same. its not faster not slower. real 0m8.212s
user 0m7.615s
sys 0m2.891s

Comment: &1.status was giving error, but i tried this `|> Stream.map(&(&1["status"]))` and result is same.

Comment: Can you post your error with 'nimble_csv' please ?

Comment: okay i have tried nimble_csv but i got confused that how to use that. so removed that code. i can give you my full code, if you can try it. bcz i dont know how to try that.